# Source pixel format is not supported by the filter in aforge.net

Tags: c#, image, image-processing, bitmap, accord.net

I am trying to develop an LPR system using `Aforge.net` ,i want to apply a filter on my image as you can see here :

```
            Bitmap a = new Bitmap(@"C:\Users\Public\Pictures\Sample Pictures\1.png");
            SobelEdgeDetector filter = new SobelEdgeDetector();
            filter.ApplyInPlace(a);
            pictureBox1.Image = a;
```

but after running i got this error:

```
Source pixel format is not supported by the filter.
```

I am so new in aforge.net.

Comment: private Bitmap a= AForge.Imaging.Image.Clone(new Bitmap(@"C:\Users\Public\Pictures\Sample Pictures\1.png"), PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb); This works for me

Answer (score 10):

As you can see from [this](http://www.aforgenet.com/framework/docs/html/2c8218cc-921c-34d8-5c88-39c652488490.htm) API documentation page, the `SobolEdgeDetector` filter only supports 8bpp grayscale images.

To apply the filter, you therefore need to convert your image to 8bpp and grayscale first, for example like this:

```
Bitmap a = AForge.Imaging.Image.Clone(
    new Bitmap(@"C:\Users\Public\Pictures\Sample Pictures\1.png"),
    PixelFormat.Format8bppIndexed);
AForge.Imaging.Image.SetGrayscalePalette(a);
```